# Anaconda and switching to new environment

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I installed Anaconda with default Python 2.7. I created python3 environment with Python 3.5 using the following command

```
conda create -n python3 python=3.5 anaconda
```

I activated python3 by issuing command `activate python3`. Then I launched `python` and typed `print 'a'` I expected this command to fail since this is python 2.x syntax, but it worked fine.
Also I ran the following code

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

and got output:

```
2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (32-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:42:13)
 [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

What is wrong, how can I confirm that I am in Python 3 environment.

Update: I am on Win 7.

Comment: If you just go to the command prompt / bash shell (depending on OS) and type `python`, what does it say?

Comment: @ode2k `Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (32-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:42:13) [MSC v.
1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: are you in linux or windows?

Comment: @JEarls I am on Win 7.

Comment: Did you launch python from the same command window in which you issued the `activate python3` command?

Comment: Yes, I tested everything in one CMD windows. I was going to do same testing in PyCharm afterwards.

Comment: Are you using PowerShell or the standard Windows command window?

Comment: I am using standard Windows command window.

Comment: I guess I know the source of the problem. I don't have admin right to my PC. When command line Anaconda was creating environment, it probably gave me a couple of error messages which I did not notice. I tried Anaconda Navigator to create environment and could not proceed without admin rights.

Comment: Anaconda can be installed "locally" just for you, and even if it isn't you can create new Conda environments that are "local" (just for you).  IOW, you don't need admin privs to use Anaconda.  What you're trying to do should work and if it isn't there could also be `PATH` and other environment variables interfering.  You should be able to run the Python command `import sys; print(sys.executable)` and `import sys; print(sys.path)` to see what comes up.  `import os; print(os.environ)` might also be informative to see if there are `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` settings that are interfering here.